# Cocoa Custom Status Menu with text view

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nstextview, nsmenuitem

I've created a status menu following some hints here and sone from other sites. It shows a an NSTextView as a line item and has check spelling as you type on, which is exactly what I want (quick way to check a misspelled word). The text view area behaves as expected by highlighting the misspelled word and all.

All works well except for one thing: when I "Control-click" on the misspelled word to get options or guesses on the possible correctly spelled word, it does not popup the context menu.

In Interface Builder I've linked a list item to a custom view containing the NSTextView ... I can send the xcode project code to anyone who would like to examine it further. As a reference I followed this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HRPMFNDcfLY and modified it slightly.

I'm a beginner, so please be kind; any hints or tips would be much appreciated. Thanks ...